# How to fix Hibernate Named Native Query's Where clause with IN

Tags: hibernate, where-clause, named-query

This query will return 17 data from the database with IN clause.

But if i assigned variable for that it gives 0 in return.

Can someone help me what went wrong?
Thanks you.

````
``` @NamedNativeQuery(name = "CustomerPayeeTransaction.getCustomerPayeeTransactionsForTotalTransactionEmail", query = "" +
            "  select cpt.merchant_id, cpt.merchant_transaction_id, cpt.created_datetime, cpt.amount " +
            "  from customer_payee_transactions cpt"+
            "  inner join appl_inte_payment_gateway aipg on cpt.payment_gateway_id = aipg.integrated_payment_gateway_id"+
            "  inner join appl_cus_paye_trx_statuses acpts on cpt.cus_paye_trx_status_id = acpts.cus_paye_trx_status_id"+
            "  where (cpt.payment_gateway_id = :ipgId)"+
            "  and (acpts.name in ('CG_Pending'))")
````

````
    ```String statusList = "('CG_Pending','PG_Pending')";
query.setParameter("statusId",statusList);
 @NamedNativeQuery(name = "CustomerPayeeTransaction.getCustomerPayeeTransactionsForTotalTransactionEmail", query = "" +
                "  select cpt.merchant_id, cpt.merchant_transaction_id, cpt.created_datetime, cpt.amount " +
                "  from customer_payee_transactions cpt"+
                "  inner join appl_inte_payment_gateway aipg on cpt.payment_gateway_id = aipg.integrated_payment_gateway_id"+
                "  inner join appl_cus_paye_trx_statuses acpts on cpt.cus_paye_trx_status_id = acpts.cus_paye_trx_status_id"+
                "  where (cpt.payment_gateway_id = :ipgId)"+
                "  and (acpts.name in :statusList)")
````

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this In hibernate rather than String

**statusList = "('CG_Pending','PG_Pending')";**

**List statusIds = Arrays.asList("PG_Success","CG_Pending");**

Then Hibernate automatically apply the required conditions.